# WooCommerce: Add class to product filter attribute option

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to style some filter options in the WooCommerce category archives.

For example: there is a filter for the type of cars. Let's say pickups, suv, sportscar, ...
Every option should get an own icon. Therefore I need a class for every option.
In the best case it would be the ID of the attribute.

I found a plugin to add CSS classes for widgets (https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-css-classes/) but not for the options/attributes.

At the moment it looks like this:

```
<ul class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list">
    <li class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item wc-layered-nav-term ">...</li>
    <li class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item wc-layered-nav-term ">...</li>
    <li class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item wc-layered-nav-term ">...</li>
</ul>
```

It would be nice, if I could add an extra class like `wc-layered-nav-term-id`.

Here you can see the same HTML structure as in my example (scroll down to the colors): https://themes.woocommerce.com/storefront/product-category/clothing/blouses/

Is there any filter I could use to add such a class?

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS3 selector like below if you have don't unique id or classes. you can see here all selectors. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```css
.woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list > li:nth-child(1){
background:red;
}

.woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list > li:nth-child(2){
background:gray;
}

.woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list > li:nth-child(3){
background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list">
    <li class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item wc-layered-nav-term ">pickups</li>
    <li class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item wc-layered-nav-term ">suv</li>
    <li class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item wc-layered-nav-term ">sportscar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the list is changing based on the selected fitlers and I could know in which position an item is

Comment: can you please provide site url

Comment: unfortunately it's an local environment. But you can see the filter here (scroll down to the colors). You can see the same HTML structure as in my example: https://themes.woocommerce.com/storefront/product-category/clothing/blouses/